# Запрет вводд строк в класс целого числа

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте,подскажите пожалуйста.

Я реализую класс `Int` , перегружая операторы и реализуя некоторые функции для класса.

Я имею два конструктор с 1 аргументом и копирования.

```
Int(int val):value(val) {}//конструктор с 1 аргументом

Int(const Int& obj)//конструктор копирования 
{
    value=obj.value;
}
```

Тело функции `main():` (создавая объект,используя `()` и `=`)

```
int main()
{
    Int n(10);
    Int n2 = n;
    Int n3(15);
    Int n5 = 12;


    std::cout << "Res plus: " << n + n3 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Res min: " <<n-n3 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Res multip: " << n*n2<< std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать `защиту от дурака` от ввода букв и других символов? Т.е. чтобы я не смог определить объект как: `Int="152";` или  `Int="abc";` ,например.

Думаю,что нужно в конструкторе по умолчанию реализовать такую защиту...

Comment: Вот это - `Int(int val):value(val) {}` - **не** конструктор по умолчанию...

Comment: @Harry конструктор с одним аргументом

Comment: Да. А что такое конструктор по умолчанию?

Comment: @Harry конструктор без аргументов:)

Comment: [Голосом Горбачева] Ну вот мы и достигли консенсуса... :)

Comment: @harry я исправился:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Система типов - вполне достаточная защита...

Напишите

```
Int n5 = "12";
```

и вы получите ошибку.

Приведите пример, где ваш дурак пробьет защиту :)

Answer (score 3):

Защита от дурака в С++ включена по умолчанию. Такой код просто не будет компилироваться. Так как нет допустимого преобразования из `const char *` (которым является строка) в `int` или `Int`, а только для этих типов конструктор будет объявлен.